# XOR Encryption in C with key

Tags: c, encryption, encoding, xor

I am trying a simple XOR encryption in C/C++ for Windows. To achieve this I am using a key "SECRETKEY" and a character array "payload". If at some point the value of current key value is equal to that of the current payload value, then the result is 0x00, therefore terminating the string. What's a common workaround?

```
const char key[] = "tSECRETKEY";


void XORCipher(char * payload) {
    
    // Key pointer
    int j = 0;

    int a = sizeof(payload);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(payload); i++) {
        *(payload + i) = *(payload + i) ^ key[j];
        j++;

        if (j == sizeof(key))
            j = 0;
    }

}

int main()
{
    char payload[] = "test";

    XORCipher(payload);
    XORCipher(payload);

    printf("%s\n", payload);

    return 0;
}
```

Result is empty, as expected.

Comment: Using the `sizeof` operator on a pointer gives you the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to. Your beginners material should have taught you how to get the length of a null-terminated string (which you already use).

Comment: And please don't add tags for irrelevant and totally different languages.

Comment: an array of `char` is not necessarily terminated by a `0`. Its your choice. By using `strlen` you chose to work with `0` terminated strings

Comment: The result of the kind of encoding you are performing can no longer safely be considered a string, for exactly the reason you describe.  It must be considered binary data, and as such, you must track and convey its length separately from the data themselves.

Comment: On a couple of different notes, `*(payload + i)` is *exactly* equal to `payload[i]`. The latter, using array indexing syntax, is usually easier to read and understand at a quick glance, not to mention that it's less to write. And your XOR operation might not yield actual printable characters.

Comment: Side note: presumably it's just a typo one way or the other, but in fact no, it appears you are not using "SECRETKEY" as your key.  You are using "tSECRETKEY".  But what you probably don't recognize is that you are including its null terminator among the key bytes, which I bet you didn't mean to do.

Comment: Encryption works with plaintexts, cyphertexts and keys. Normally, neither of those is a string. They are arrays of bytes, not to be presumed null-terminated (or containing printable characters). The length should be supplied separately along each one of them. I recommend you approach your task from this position. Sometimes you can get away with the assumption that these arrays are in fact null-terminated strings, but then you need to verify that this assumption works in your specific case. Whereas not assuming anything like that always works.

Answer (score 2):

> If at some point the value of current key value is equal to that of the current payload value, then the result is 0x00, therefore terminating the string. What's a common workaround?

Measure the length of the plaintext string. Let *L* be that length. Encrypt the string. Write *L* bytes of the ciphertext to output. In other words, do not use functions that use a null character to terminate a string; use code and functions that write a definite specified number of characters. You can use `fwrite(ciphertext, 1, L, stdout)` for this.

Note that typical “terminal” software has a number of characters that do not print recognizable distinct characters. The null character is one such, and there are others. So merely writing raw characters to a terminal is not a useful way to convey ciphertext. It might work for writing to a file. For a terminal, you need some other way to represent ciphertext, such as converting it to hexadecimal.

If you want the output to convey the length of the ciphertext, you must also write that or indicate it in some way.

Comment: You'll also need to switch the handle to binary mode on some systems (Windows) to prevent CRLF<=>LF conversion.